# How to filter a response in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a test posts limited to user.

i try to get post of user but i don't know how i filter response data.

```
def test_posts_limited_to_user(self):
    """Test retrieving posts for user"""
    user2 = get_user_model().objects.create_user('admin@admin.com', 'adminPASS@123')
    sample_post(user=user2)
    sample_post(user=self.user)

    res = self.client.get(POSTS_URL, {'user': self.user.id})

    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=self.user)
    serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    self.assertEqual(len(posts), 1)
    self.assertEqual(res.data, serializer.data)
```

but it return all posts

Comment: What is the `sample_post` function doing?

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is. Do you want to filter the json response returned by the API of filter the model objects using the ORM? please make your question clearer and more elaborate

Comment: Yes i want to return the json response

`res = self.client.get(POSTS_URL, {'user': self.user.id})`

i want to get posts of this user

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by add a filter in View

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """Retrieve the posts for the authenticated user"""
    user = self.request.query_params.get('user')
    queryset = self.queryset
    if user:
        queryset = queryset.filter(user=user)

    return queryset.all()
```